# ‎$‎A‎$ ‎is a ‎$ ‎C‎^{*}$-‎algebra‎ .........

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I ‎need ‎help ‎on ‎proving ‎the ‎below ‎question:‎

‎suppose ‎that ‎‎$‎A‎$ ‎is a $‎C‎^{*}$-‎algebra ‎and‎ ‎$\varphi:A‎‎\to‎‎\mathbb{C}$ is a‎ linear,‎ ‎bounded ‎map ‎so ‎that $\forall a \in A, \varphi ( a^{*}a ) = 0$.

Does this mean that $\varphi = 0$?‎

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following. Any positive element $z$ in $A$ is of the form $z=a^*a$ for some $a\in A$ (non-trivial fact, some take it as a definition). Moreover, each element in a C$^\ast$-algebra is a linear combination of at most four positive elements (a consequence of the continuous functional calculus). Now, exploit linearity.

Comment: excuse me, can you explain your answer

Answer (score 1):

Ok, suppose you have some $a\in A$. Now, an element in $A$ is a sum of at most four positive elements, say $a = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4$. Now, write $a_i = b_i^*b_i$ for some $b_i \in A$ (each $a_i$ is positive). We have $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b_1^*b_1) + ... + \varphi(b_4^*b_4) = 0$ by linearity.

Comment: we know that ‎$ a‎ =‎ ‎a‎^{+}  -‎ ‎‎ ‎a‎^{‎-‎} , ‎‎\qquad ‎ a‎^{+}  -‎ ‎‎ ‎a‎^{‎-‎} ‎\geq ‎0‎ ‎$.Is this the proof does not create a problem? (excuse me i have recently started this field.)

Comment: Yes the result you refer to states that self-adjoint elements of the form $a=a^+ - a^-$, where $a^+, a^- \geq 0$. Since any element is a sum of two self-adjoints, any element is the sum of at most four positive elements.

Comment: Not a sum. A *linear combination*.

Comment: Oh yes you're absolutely right.